# "can't read /etc/fstab: No such file or directory" when mounting system?

Tags: mount, system

I am running CyanogenMod 7.2, and when I type `mount system` in Terminal Emulator, it gives me

```
mount: can't read '/etc/fstab': No such file or directory
```

What's wrong? It obviously can mount the /system partition because the device boots fine, but yet I am getting this message.

[image: ls of /system/etx]

Comment: Hmm... I think a bit more context might be helpful here.

Comment: @dotVezz It started this morning when I tried to use Chainfire's NoMoarPowah! It said 101Can't mount system, so I got the terminal emulator and tried it. It apparently can't mount it either.

Comment: Hmm... I could have sworn that there was an `/etc/fstab` until Android 4.3. I'm kind of surprised that your 2.4 doesn't seem to have it. Or was it `/etc/vold.fstab`? What's in your `/etc/` directory?

Comment: Bluetooth, wifi, etc. GPS.conf, vender, and more, I can't list them all. no fstab though

Comment: And just to confirm, no vold.fstab either?

Comment: Editted question, I do have one of those